# comparação string + linkedList

Tags: java, string, testes

Bom noite, estou tentando comparar uma string com uma linked list porem não estou tendo sucesso, a linked list esta sendo retornada um valor de outra função porem vou botar aqui a saída da linked list.

```
assertEquals("nome composto",frase.converterCamelCase("nomeComposto"));
```

o teste acusa o acontecido.

java.lang.AssertionError: expected:< nome composto> but was:<[nome, composto]>

como posso fazer para esse teste passar?

Comment: o método tem que retornar uma linkedlist, pois este expresso que o método tem que retornar esse tipo.

Comment: Consegui ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

O que você quer testar na verdade é a saída desse método `converterCamelCase`, sendo assim eu faria o seguinte, testaria que para cada item presente no `LinkedList` retornado desse método esteja de acordo com a string passada como parâmetro, em código ficaria algo desse tipo:

```
assertEquals("nome",frase.converterCamelCase("nomeComposto").get(0));
assertEquals("composto",frase.converterCamelCase("nomeComposto").get(1));
```